# RelativeLayout does not expand with the heights of view elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Relative layout the is set to `wrap_content` in height. It has 2 TextView and 2 EditText. However, the RelativeLayout does not match to the height of EditTexts.

Dashed Rectangle is the region highlighted by android studio preview tool as the borders of RelativeLayout.

The actual problem is that when I run the app the bottom edittext kind of goes below the Relative layout and so its bottom part disappears. Thereby, user can't see that bottom line and don't know that there is a textfield.

**Android Studio Preview:**

[image]

**Problem and Result on Emulator:**

[image]

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberOfDaysTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/initialNumberOfDays"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="58sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daysText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberOfDaysTextView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/daysText"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.Space
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/fromTextView"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fromDate"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/toTextView"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="date" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculateDaysButton"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:text="@string/calculateButtonText"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT: *Another solution that has worked:***

TextView must be aligned to baseline of EditText and not the reverse way!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/fromDate"
        android:text="@string/fromTextView"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fromDate"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:text="@string/toTextView"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fromDate"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="date" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the problem is the dashed rectangle? can't understand very well..

Comment: Dashed Rectangle is the region highlighted by android studio preview tool as the borders of RelativeLayout. The actual problem is that the bottom edittext sinks below the Relative layout and so its bottom part disappears. Thereby, user can't see that bottom line and don't know that there is a textfield

Comment: can you share a screen of the problem?

Comment: Above image contains a problem ? Otherwise screen share which reproduce exact issue.

Comment: Yes, it is now in the question

Comment: @jaydroider @ddb I have tried to set manually the height of RelativeLayout and EditTexts and when there was enough `dp` bottom line was present. But I don't think that hardcoding is good way

Comment: Why does one EditText have a fixed height and one use wrap_content?  android:layout_height="45dp"

Comment: Sorry, it was one of my trials to solve the problem. It behaves the same when both edittexts are set to `wrap_content`

Comment: a workaround could be to put a simple empty transparent view below the issued edittext, with 1dp height

Comment: @Marat Check and try with my answer let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: @ddb Interestingly only after setting height to 11dp I could get the bottom line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should use `Linear Layout` instead of `Relative Layout`.
>
> Check out below code i have done some modification and applied with `Linear Layout`. You can modify with `margin` , `height` , `width`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/numberOfDaysTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="58sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daysText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/numberOfDaysTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Day"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:text="to"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fromDate"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"

                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="28dp"

                android:ems="10"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:text="feom"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/toDate"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"

                android:ems="10"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:inputType="date" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculateDaysButton"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
            android:text="@string/calculateButtonText"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Hope this Solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fromDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="from"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fromDate"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/toDate" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="to"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/toDate"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fromDate"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toDatePickerTextView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="date" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a fixed size for edittext, try removing those so that you can achieve your expectations. Also use singleline=true/maxLines=1 for edit text- this is best practice.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have uploaded wrong version of that particular line of code. Take a look at updated code. It is still behaving in the same way